# How to I show a finite discrete set is closed or not?

Tags: general-topology

I need to show that whether $\{ 1,2,3,...,50\}$ is closed or not.

I could rewrite the set as $\{x\in N : 0 \leq x \leq 50 \}$, which is bounded, so it is closed?

Or another idea is to just say: We can have $x = 1$ or $x = 50$, but we can not take an open ball around any of those points, thus it can't be open. But this doesn't neccesarily mean that it is closed, does it?

Comment: Under which topology?

Comment: I don't know why you single out $x = 1$ and $x = 50$; there is no ball (in the usual metric) about *any* point of your set that is contained in the set.  Nonetheless, your last point is right:  not being open doesn't mean being closed (nor, for that matter, does being closed mean not being open).

Comment: No.  Not open does not mean closed.  But the complement (every number that *isn't* 1 ... 50) being open does.  And for every point *not* 1...50 we can get an open ball that contains no element 1..50.  Or note.  Take any point in x in R.  We can find a small enough ball around R so that other than x itself the ball will have no number 1...50.  So x is not a limit point and no limit points exist.  So that means all limit points (all zero of them) are in 1...50 so {1...50} is closed.  **IF** your topology is R with the euclidean metric...

Comment: @fleablood I am not sure I understand. So, taking any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we can find a small enough open ball around $\mathbb{R}$, s.t. no number except $x$ from $\{ 1...50 \}$ is contained in the open ball? I am confused when you say open ball around $R$?

Comment: Not an open ball around R.  An open ball around any real number x. Pick x in R.  x can be any real number.  If the ball is small enough the ball won't have any 1...50 in the ball (except maybe x itself, if x is 1...50...but if x is then there won't be any *other* 1..50 in the ball).  So x is not a limit point.  So there are no limit points to A at all. A set that doesn't have any limit points is closed.  (Because there are no limit points outside the set.)

Comment: Oh, I guess I did make typo.  Not around R.  That makes no sense.  Around x.  The idea is a discrete set has no limit points and therefore most be closed.

Answer (score 2):

Bounded does not imply closed, as is seen by taking the set $(0,1)$ for instance.

However, finite implies closed in $\tau_1$ spaces, since a finite set is a finite union of points, which are closed. Since you are probably talking about $\mathbb{R}$ with its canonical topology, we have a metric space (hence Hausdorff, hence $\tau_1$), and the result follows.

I'm posting the above answer since you tagged in general topology. For a simpler approach, for any point $p$ not in your set $A=\{1,\cdots, 50\}$, consider the ball of radius $\min\{d(p,x_i) \mid x_i \in A\}$ around $p$. This will be a neighbourhood which does not intersect $A$, hence $p$ is not a limit point of $A$.

Comment: So, since you write radius $x_i \in A$, so min would be $1$ in this case?

Comment: @Fredrik I didn't write radius $x_i \in A$. What I wrote is that the radius is the minimum of the values $d(p,x_i)$, with $x_i$ running through the elements of $A$. Note that this obviously will depend on what $p$ you are considering.

Comment: Sorry, yes, my mistake. However, In relation to the first part of your comment. 

By using de Morgans Laws on closed sets. Which I think you are refering to, where one of the laws says that the union of any finite number of closed sets is also closed.

Could I argue since that the because a singleton $\{ x \}$ is closed, the union of all numbers $0 \leq x \leq 50$, where $x \in \mathbb{N}$, the union would then also be closed?

Answer (score 1):

In $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb Q$ with the usual Euclidean metric any finite set is closed.  I'll prove that in a moment but I have to point out that I can find literally infinite topologies where {1...50} is closed but not open, open but not closed, closed and open, and neither.

When asking if set is closed you have to indicate what space and what topology you are talking about.

So let's assume $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb Q$ with Euclidean metric.  A finite set $A$ can be ordered and labeled as $a_1 < a_2 < ..... <a_n$.  If $q \not \in A$ then either $q < a_1$, $q > a_n$, or $a_i < q < a_{i+1}$.  Let $\epsilon = \min (|q -a_i|; a_i < q, |a_j - q|; a_j >q)$.  (In other words, let $\epsilon$ be the closest distance between $q$ and a member of $a$).

Then there are no members of $A$ in $(q-\epsilon,q + \epsilon)$.  So $(q - \epsilon, q + \epsilon) \subset A^c$. So $q$ is an interior point of $A^c$ so $Z^c$ is open so $A$ is closed.

[Furthermore $A$ is not open.  For any $a_i \in A$ and $\epsilon > 0$ then $(a_i - \epsilon, a_i + \epsilon)$ contain infinitely many points which at most finite of them are in $A$ so $(a_i - \epsilon, a_i + \epsilon)\not \subset A$, so $a_i$ is not an interior point of $A$.  So $A$ is not open.]

But Now.  If I set my topology to be R with the trivial topology that only R and the empty set are open, the {1... 50} is neither open nor closed as neither it nor its compliment  is either the universal set nor the empty set.

If I set toplogy to be the discrete toplogy then every set, including {1... 50} is both open and closed.

If I chose a toplogy where R, the empty set, and the set of each integer is open, then {1... 50} is open because it is a finite union of open sets.  But it is not closed as its complement is not open.

If I chose a toplogy where R, the empty set, and the set of even integers is opne, then {1... 50} is neither open nor closed.  Etc.

Answer (score 0):

Under the discrete metric, every set is an open set.

However, under the standard topology, it is closed.

Usually the easiest way to prove closure to to prove the the complement of the set is open.

Lets call your set $A,$  and its complement $A'.$

$\forall x \in A'$, there is a point in $A$ that is closest to $x.$  (We can say this because $A$ is finite.)

Lets call this distance $\delta.$

There exists a neighborhood or radius less than $\delta$ that contains $x$ but contains no point in $A.$

$A'$ open.  $A$ is closed.

Comment: For what it's worth, it seems that @Fredrik is using $N$ for the set of *all* positive integers, not just of the putative closed subset of it with 50 elements.  (Also, it is worth noting, per the last question in the post, that 'open' and 'closed' are not exclusive—even in the same topology, much less in different ones—which a casual reading of your first two sentences might seem to suggest.)

Comment: right.  I will clean up the ambiguity.